# What mechanism overwrites the return address of a stack frame, preventing certain buffer overflow exploits?

Tags: c, linux, x86, stack, buffer-overflow

**Context:**    The source code shown below is compiled using the first command shown below. The resulting executable is then loaded into gdb and run using the second command shown below. A segfault is then produced (as expected) and the contents of the EIP register are examined using gdb. Two cases are observed.

*Case 1:* The hex address supplied in the second command shown below is **NOT** the address of some function in the currently loaded executable. After running this command, EIP is examined and contains the address supplied by the command (as expected).

*Case 2:* The hex address supplied in the second command shown below **IS** the address of some function in the currently loaded executable (secret() in this case). After running this command, EIP is examined and contains the address 0xffffd200. In this case, several code variations have been tried and the resulting value in EIP is always 0xffffd200.

**Question:**
 What mechanism would overwrite the stack frame return address after a buffer overflow were used to set this address to the address of some function in the running executable?

**Notes:**

OS = Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

GCC Version = 5.4.0

Architecture = x86

**Source:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void secret() {

    printf("success\n");
}

void vuln(char *input) {

    char buffer[10];
    strcpy(buffer, input);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    vuln(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

**First Command:**

```
gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector test.c
```

**Second Command (in gdb):**

```
run `python -c 'print "a"*22 + "\x56\x84\x04\x08"'`
```

Comment: Perhaps your hack is (partially) successful in case 2, and the EIP value you observe in that case results from "returning" to function `secret()` and the action of that function.

Comment: The compiler will typically allocate the `buffer` at an aligned address. See [the disassembly](https://godbolt.org/g/7jILbk). The fixed length 22 may not work across code changes. Furthermore [Ubuntu uses ASLR](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Security/Features#Address_Space_Layout_Randomisation_.28ASLR.29).

Comment: Regarding what's been said about ASLR, I had considered that, but that doesn't explain how the supplied address is being successfully written into EIP in cases where the supplied address does not belong to that of a function in the running executable. Regarding what John Bollinger said, that's something I had not considered, but if that were the case I'd expect the printf function from secret() to be executed, but it isn't.

Comment: I went over everything again today and @JohnBollinger you were mostly correct. The secret function was indeed running and the 0xffffd200 value found in EIP was the result of secret attempting to return, causing a segfault. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!